# When using Flask-Login and Peewee as the ORM, is there a need to create the login attributes on the database?

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-login

The [Flask-Login documentation states](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) that you should create some attributes for your User model to handle some aspects of the authentication and session handling process, which is fair.

However, when adding these attributes to the User model when using Peewee as the ORM for the project, that means those fields will be created on the database as well whenever the database boostrap script runs, because those three are now attributes of said User model class:

```py
class User(Model):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    # required by Flask-Login
    is_authenticated = BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
    is_anonymous = BooleanField(default=False)

    # required by Flask-Login
    def get_id(self):
        return super().get_id()

    class Meta:
        database = SqliteDatabase(DEFAULT_DB_NAME)
```

So my questions are:

1. Does it mean that those are required at the database level, or is it ok not to have them there (that is: just in memory)?
2. If they are not required at the db level, then how can I exclude those three attributes from the table creation statements when creating the database for the first time, as Peewee creates the tables according to the class attributes?
3. For Flask-Login, would the creation of a class that is not included in the Peewee's models list work (if #2 is true)?

Comment: I suggest checking out this post, as it provides some more concrete detail: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins -- I expect that is_authenticated and is_anonymous do not need to be stored in the database, but I'm not positive.

Comment: If you don't care about using Flask-Login, here is a very simple example of how login works with flask+peewee: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/ade292f7abd01d60ff60764d02d1c5fa15988716/examples/twitter/app.py#L36 (note you will want to hash the password more securely than in the example!)

Comment: Thanks @coleifer, I figured it out by testing and reading Flask-Login's documentation. It is indeed not necessary to have those in the database, and there's a way to not have the attributes on the model by using inheritance. I'll add the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on the Flask-Login's documentation:

> To make implementing a user class easier, you can inherit from UserMixin, which provides default implementations for all of these properties and methods. (It’s not required, though.)

By using the UserMixin class in my model, I don't need to manually create the attributes on my file, and so Peewee doesn't create the columns on the database:

```py
...
from flask_login import UserMixin
...

class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(null=False)
    password = CharField(null=False)
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def get_id(self):
        return super().get_id()

    class Meta:
        database = SqliteDatabase(DEFAULT_DB_NAME)
```